# ¿A qué se debe este error: “Notice: Uninitialized string offset”? Estoy tratando de guardar varios datos en un insert en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php
    $localhost = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "restaurante";

    $connect = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if($connect->connect_error) {
      die("Connection Failed : " . $connect->connect_error);
    } else {

    }

    if($_POST) {    


    foreach ($_POST as $comida) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO detalle_venta (id_detalle,rela_mesas,rela_comidas,cantidad,rela_bebidas,cantidad_bebidas,fecha_venta,hora_venta,rela_persona,cantidad_total)
values('".$comida['id_ventas']."','".$comida['rela_mesas']."','".$comida['nombre_comida']."','".$comida['cantidad']."','".$comida['nombre_producto']."','".$comida['cantidad_bebida']."','".$comida['fecha_venta']."','".$comida['hora_venta']."','".$comida['rela_persona']."','".$comida['sub_totalValue']."')";

    $connect->query($sql) or die("Error");

    }
    $connect->close();

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Estás intentando guardar información en tipos de dato incompatibles, probablemente. Por ejemplo, guardando strings dentro de tipos de datos int.

Comment: y como podria solucionar eso? porque es para un proyecto y apena se sobre php

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenido a Stackoverflow.

Tu error ocurre porque `$_POST` es un array unidimensional, y en el `foreach` lo intentas leer como una array multidimensional. Los datos posteados en tu caso tendrían esta apariencia:

```
$_POST=[   'id_ventas'=>1,
           'rela_mesas'=>'a', 
           'nombre_comida'=>'b', 
           'cantidad'=>2, 
           'nombre_producto'=>'c',
           'cantidad_bebida'=>3,
           'fecha_venta'=>'d',
           'hora_venta'=>'e',
           'rela_persona'=>'f',
           'sub_totalValue'=>'g',
      ];
```

Para poder leerlo como muestras en tu código tendrías que meter a `$_POST` dentro de un array, para hacerlo asociativo, haciendo algo así: `foreach ( array($_POST) as $comida ) { //... lectura de datos }` .

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
foreach ( array($_POST) as $comida ) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO detalle_venta (
                id_detalle, 
                rela_mesas, 
                rela_comidas, 
                cantidad, 
                rela_bebidas, 
                cantidad_bebidas, 
                fecha_venta, 
                hora_venta, 
                rela_persona, 
                cantidad_total )
            values 
            (
                '$comida[id_ventas]',
                '$comida[rela_mesas]',
                '$comida[nombre_comida]',
                '$comida[cantidad]',
                '$comida[nombre_producto]',
                '$comida[cantidad_bebida]',
                '$comida[fecha_venta]',
                '$comida[hora_venta]',
                '$comida[rela_persona]',
                '$comida[sub_totalValue]'
            )";
    echo $sql.PHP_EOL;
}
```

La salida en este caso sería esta, sin ningún tipo de `Notice`:

```
INSERT INTO detalle_venta (
                    id_detalle, 
                    rela_mesas, 
                    rela_comidas, 
                    cantidad, 
                    rela_bebidas, 
                    cantidad_bebidas, 
                    fecha_venta, 
                    hora_venta, 
                    rela_persona, 
                    cantidad_total )
                values 
                (
                    '1',
                    'a',
                    'b',
                    '2',
                    'c',
                    '3',
                    'd',
                    'e',
                    'f',
                    'g'
                )
```

Podrás observar que en estos casos, para evitar tantas concatenaciones con `.` puedes poner toda la cadena entre comillas dobles, y luego dentro puedes poner las claves del array sin ningún tipo de comilla: `$comida[id_ventas]` ... `$comida[rela_mesas]`... etc. Otra cosa que debes tener en cuenta es que en la consulta, los valores numéricos no deben ir entre comillas simples.

## Otra forma no estándar de resolver esto

Dado que `$_POST` es un array, podrías obtener todos los valores separados por comas y rodeados de comillas simples usando simplemente `implode`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$allValues = "'" . implode("','", $_POST) . "'";
$sql = "INSERT INTO detalle_venta (
                    id_detalle, 
                    rela_mesas, 
                    rela_comidas, 
                    cantidad, 
                    rela_bebidas, 
                    cantidad_bebidas, 
                    fecha_venta, 
                    hora_venta, 
                    rela_persona, 
                    cantidad_total )
                values 
                ($allValues)";
echo $sql;
```

En este caso, lo que creamos en `$alValues` es la lista de valores que se quiere insertar:

```
'1','a','b','2','c','3','d','e','f','g'
```

He llamado esta forma «no estándar» porque en ese caso los valores numéricos quedarías rodeados también por comillas simples y esto rompe el estándar de cara a la consulta, ya que, como se dijo antes, en SQL los valores que son numéricos deberían estar sin comillas simples, aunque esto funcione, podría ser problemático y no optimiza el código dado que obliga al manejador a una conversión de esos datos.

---

Finalmente, aunque esto resuelva tu problema, considera evitar este tipo de prácticas en las inserciones. Este código es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*, lo cual supone un grave agujero de seguridad en el código. Por otra parte no hay control de los datos. Si alguna de las claves no es enviada en el `$_POST` este código emitirá un `PHP Notice:  Undefined index` en ese caso. Para inserciones tienes que recoger cada dato uno por uno y luego usar consultas preparadas.

Comment: estoy probando el primero que me recomendaste pero solo me guarda un solo dato en la base, y lo que quiero es meter varios datos, porque estoy haciendo un sistema de pedidos de comidas como proyecto para mi institucion, y lo que quiero es que me guarde varios datos

Comment: @LucianoVilla habría que ver qué datos hay en el POST para poder ayudarte. Si es posible haz un `print_r($_POST);` y agrégalo a la pregunta para ver cómo están estructurados los datos. Me avisas cuando lo hayas agregado.

Comment: Buena respuesta, padre. Saludos.

Comment: ´Array ( [id_ventas] => 1578115808 [fecha_venta] => 04-01-2020 [hora_venta] => 02:30 [rela_persona] => 24 [rela_mesas] => 1 [estado_comida] => 1 [pago] => 1 [nombre_comida] => 2 [precio_comidaValue] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [cantidad] => 1 [totalValue] => Array ( [0] => 250.00 [1] => 250.00 ) [nombre_producto] => 4 [totalValueBebida] => Array ( [0] => 200.00 [1] => ) [cantidad_bebida] => 1 [sub_totalValue] => 700.00 [insertar] => )´  Buenas, disculpe por responder tardde, esto me sale

Comment: ¿Cuando decías *varios datos*  te referías a varias filas o a que faltaban datos por insertar? En lo que muestras hay una sola fila estructurada con arrays anidados y demás. Sería bueno que aclares lo que quiere decir *varios datos*. Sospecho que hay un problema en la forma en que organizas los datos para mandarlos en el `$_POST`.

Comment: sii varios datos, te explico, en mi formulario tengo 4 filas predeterminada en el que coloco las comidas de los clientes y despues tengo un boton que al hacer click me inserta una nueva fila para las bebidas, mi problema es que cuando hize la prueba, puse 3 comidas y una bebida, pero cuando lo mando al post no me tira error pero en la base me guarda solamente una fila, y mi idea es que guarde varias filas que en este caso seria los pedidos de la comida y bebida

Comment: No entiendo mucho... si es un sólo cliente, ¿por qué hay que insertar tres filas? ¿O hablamos de tres clientes que han hecho cada uno su pedido?

Comment: Son tres clientes que han hecho cada uno su pedido, por eso en el mismo formulario cargo por defecto 4 filas, tenes Facebook? Así te mando una imagen del formulario para que entiendas un poco